# Choice left element with multiple (+) quantifier does not become an array

Tags: antlrworks, antlr4

A fragment of my grammar is:

```
potentialAttribute: DATA EQUAL LEFTPARENTH (data+ | REAL+) RIGHTPARENTH SEMICOLON;
```

Then, in visitor, I should ask `potentialAttribute` if text read was `data+` or `REAL+`. Since both of them have `+` symbol, both must be arrays. Nevertheless, only `REAL()` is a `List<TerminalNode>`, while `data()` remains as `TerminalNode`.

BUT if I change choice order, like:

```
potentialAttribute: DATA EQUAL LEFTPARENTH (REAL+ | data+) RIGHTPARENTH SEMICOLON;
```

It is `REAL` the one which does not work.

What can cause this?

(I can post the whole compilable code if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a bug in ANTLR 4. You can report issues to the project issue tracker on GitHub:

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues